# calling php using js

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, alert

ok so I have this in my HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="load2.php"> </script>
```

I saw somewhere you could call a php file like that and the javascript contained in it will be rendered on the page once echoed.
So in my PHP file i have this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $storeArray[] =  $row['DayNum']; }
            $length = count($storeArray);
```

I connected to my database and stuff and pulled those records and stored them in an array. Now my problem is alerting them using js. This is what I have:

```
echo " function test() {

                for(var i = 0; i<$length; i++){
                    alert($storeArray[i]);
                }   
        }
            ";
```

The test() function is being onloaded in my HTML page, but for nothing the values in the array won't alert. Any help please?

Comment: Maybe use AJAX, create simple API for this. That will be more clearly.

Comment: Are you actually calling that function?

Comment: You are writing `$storeArray[1]` literally to the Javascript code, rather than writing it's value.

Comment: Are $storeArray and $length in your JS code?  You actually have to send the values back for JS to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo " function test() {

                for(var i = 0; i<$length; i++){
                    alert($storeArray[i]);
                }   
        }
            ";
```

This code is literally writing what you have written above. It's not completely clear, but I believe your intent is to loop over the contents of your database data, and alert that to the browser with `alert()` function.

You can achieve this in a couple of ways.

**Write multiple alert statements**

```
echo "function test() {"; //Outputting Javascript code.

for($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){ //Back in PHP mode - notice how we aren't inside of a string.
    $value = $storeArray[$i];
    echo "alert($value)"; //Outputting Javascript code again.
}
echo "}"; //Outputting Javascript code to close your javascript "test()" function.
```

**Write a Javascript array, then loop over it in Javascript**

```
echo "function test() {";
echo "    var storeArray = ['" . implode("','", $storeArray) . "'];";
echo "    for (var i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) {";
echo "        alert(storeArray[i]);";
echo "    };";
echo "}";
```

Finally, you could use AJAX and JSON to load the data, rather than outputting a JS file from PHP. That is an entirely different topic, though, and you should search StackOverflow for more examples as there are numerous questions and answers involving it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your array contains only number, you probably have JS error. You should put your $storeArray[i] in quotes in the alert function so it considered as a string in js.

```
alert('$storeArray[i]');
```

Once printed out, the JS will look something like this

```
alert('foo');
alert('bar');
```

Whereas with your code, it would've printed it like this

```
alert(foo);
alert(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your php file include load2.php

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

in the in the top. so your browser get what it wants.

```
$i=0;
$storeArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[$i] = $row['DayNum']; 
    $i++;
}
echo "var arr = Array();";
echo "function test() {";
foreach ($storeArray as $key=>$item) {
    echo "arr[".$key."] = ".$item.";";   
}
echo "}";
echo "alert(arr);";
```

actually you can comment out the two echos containing the `<script></script>` part when including the file as `<script src="load2.php" type="text/javascript" ...`